# C++ .exe "has stopped working" after calling function twice

Tags: c++, function, crash, codeblocks

So I have a program in C++ that calls a function three times, I'm making this project using Code::Blocks and when I run the release version of the .exe it tells me that the program has stopped working and that I have to close the program. I tried calling the function just once and it works, no matter which call I leave. So it looks like it crashes only when it's called twice, regardless of which variables I pass. Any idea of why this happens?
Here's the function I call:

```
int interval(int h, int i, std::vector< std::vector<int> >& Array, int arr[], int interv)
{
    int k = i + 1;
    int P[20];
    int number;
    bool a;
    int b;
    int N;
    int maxres;
    int result[90];

    for (h = 0; h < 20; h++)
    {
        for (N = 1; N <= 90; N += 1)
        {
            result[N] = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= (k - interv); i++)
            {
                number = Array[i - 1][h] - N;
                if (number <= 0)
                    number += 90;
                for (b = 0; b < 20; b++)
                {
                    a = false;
                    if ((number == Array[i][b]) || ( (interv == 1) && (number == Array[i + 1][b]) ) || ( (interv == 2) && (number == Array[i + 2][b]) ) )
                    {
                        a = true;
                        result[N]++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!a)
                    break;
            }
           if (N == 1)
                maxres = N;
           else
           {
                if (result[N] >= result[maxres])
                    maxres = N;
           }
        }
        P[h] = maxres;
    }

    for (h = 0; h < 20; h++)
    {
        arr[h] = Array[0][h] + P[h];
        if ( arr[h] > 90 )
            arr[h] -= 90;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here are the calls:

```
int c[20];
int e[20];
int d[20];

interval(h, i, Array, c, 0);
interval(h, i, Array, e, 1);
interval(h, i, Array, d, 2);
```

Comment: Post your code maybe?

Comment: There's a bug in your code. That's all anyone can say about why it's happening. If you post the code, someone could probably find the bug.

Comment: [sigh] call it once, put a breakpoint on the entry, call it again, step through the code, find out which line causes the problem.  Repeat, if required, to check all relevant vars on the line before the crash.  If you are STILL stuck, post again, telling us know what you have found out.

Comment: You need to post the declaration and values of `h`, `i` and more importantly `Array`. You are using `Array` in `interval()` without checking if you are within range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is out-of-bounds accesses to `result`:

```
int result[90];

for (h = 0; h < 20; h++)
{
    for (N = 1; N <= 90; N += 1)   <--- Here!
    {
        result[N] = 0;
```

The allowed values for `N` are 0 to 89 (like in `for (N = 0; N != 90; ++N)`)

There might be a similar problem here

```
        for (i = 1; i <= (k - interv); i++)
```

but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: You're right, I should have noticed that! Now it works, thanks